# При попытке передать в sql-запрос переменную и отправляя запрос, в ответ приходит null

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jwt

Пишу на node.js и использую бд postgres без орм, напрямую пишу запросы.

```
class UserController {
async registration(req, res, next) {
    const {id, email, password, role} = req.body

    if (!email || !password) {
        return next(ApiError.badRequest('Некорректный email или password'))
    }
    const candidate = await db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1', [email])
    console.log(candidate)
    if (candidate) {
        return next(ApiError.badRequest('Пользователь с таким email уже существует'))
    }
    const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 5)
    const user = await db.query('INSERT INTO users (id, email, password, role) values($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *', [id, email, hashPassword, role] )

    const token = generateJwt(id, email, role)
    res.json(user)
    return res.json({token})
}
```

}

Не могу понять почему он возвращает null

Comment: Попробуйте изменить запрос на `SELECT count(*) as CNT FROM users` - что придет? Поидее, если записей нет, должна прийти 1 запись со значение 0

Comment: я понял, что он ничего и не должен присылать, если он в базе ничего не находит, что ему присылать кроме null?

Comment: поэтому я просто сделал обработку null и всё